# Placeholder for RichTextarea

Tags: visualforce

Displaying placeholder text for rich Apex:inputTextArea is not working when I use pass through variable in vf page.

Has anybody achieved using JavaScript or any other method to display placeholder.

Much appreciated.

Thanks
Sivarajan

Comment: Even i tried using Onfocus and Onblur JavaScript methods to display placeholder but not working.

Comment: Post the snippet

Comment: Here is the score snippet :  <apex:InputTextArea richText=true>.    When I applied Html-placeholder ="true" attribute with or without docuType attribute, it's not working. For RichTextArea it acts  differently. From my point of view the only solution is using JavaScript to populate the value. Any inputs ?

Comment: I have added answer please check its working for me,

Comment: Sure karthikselva , I will confirm. Did you get rich text area with toolbars above the text area ?

Comment: @Karthikselva, the below is not working because when you mention RichText ="true" in apex:inputTextArea

Answer (score 1):

You might needto more clearly explain the question, but I think you're asking about this:

You may use `<apex:inputTextArea html-placeholder="TextYouWantToEnter"></ apex:inputTextArea>`
to display the placeholders in an inputTextArea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use html attributes in apex components, you need to use  **html-[attribute name]**

Below code worked for me:

```
<apex:page controller="TestController">
    <apex:form id="changeDescription">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <p>Current description: </p>
        <p>Change description to:</p> 
        <apex:inputTextarea id="newDesc" value="{!test}" html-placeholder='Placeholder here'/><p/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Reference:** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm